# String ReplaceAll() method is not giving proper results

Tags: java

"This is the snippet of my code"

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "sourav /*the patameter*/ /*the patameter*/ /*the patameter*/";
        if (true) {
            s = s.replaceAll("\\/*the patameter\\*/", "111");
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

"As replaceAll() method takes a regex i gave the escape sequence ,Still it is not getting escaped."
"The response i am getting is sourav /*111 /*111 /*111"

"Expected response is sourav 111 111 111".
"I know this can be done with simple replace() method .But can i do it with replaceAll().Please Let me know"

Comment: Yes, `\\/*` matches "0 or more occurrences of /". It doesn't match the `*`. Perhaps you meant `\\/\\*` at the start of the pattern? (It's not clear to me that you even need to escape the forward slash.) As another hint: when something doesn't give you the results you expect, it's always best to *start* with the assumption that you're doing something wrong rather than that the standard library of a very widely-used platform is broken. If your title had "is not giving the results I expect" that would be better than "is not giving proper results"

Comment: Try [`\/\*the patameter\*\/`](https://regex101.com/r/PBUOIT/1), you have to escape the `*`

Comment: I suggest you use an online regex helper and play a bit with it.

Comment: s = s.replaceAll("\\/\\*the patameter\\*\\/", "111"); Try this

Comment: \\/\\*the patameter\\*\\/  with this it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
s.replaceAll("/\\*the patameter\\*/", "111");
```

Or even better:

```
s.replace("/*the patameter*/", "111");
```

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in my question , it can be done with Simple replace() , but wanted to do  with ReplaceAll().

Answer (score 0):

Try using the \Q and \E switches.  It's the way to declare a string literal (escape) within the regex pattern.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\Q/*the patameter\\*/\\E", "111");
```